# MySQL - numbers comparison

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got two strings, this in database:

```
"01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06"
```

and this is my PHP generated string:

```
"02, 03, 04, 06, 07, 08"
```

I want to check, in my database, which of these numbers are identical, and how many.

Comment: This is pretty vague. To start, what's the database schema and what's the applicable code generating your second string?

Comment: try somewhere along the lines of putting the 2 strings into an array with ',' as delimiter. Then sort them and compare. You should include codes from your own attempts in your question

Answer (score 1):

you need to  pull the string out into your php, split (explode) on ", " then  do an array_intersect to get the identical ones, and a count() to find how many

```
//php
$phpstring ="02, 03, 04, 06, 07, 08";

//fix the query
$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT mystring from mytable where something"));

$dbstring=$row['mystring'];

$dbarray=explode(', ' $dbstring);
$phparray=explode(', ',$phpstring);

$identicals=array_intersect($dbarray,$phparrray);

echo "there are ".count($identicals)." identical elements: ". implode(",",$identicals);
```

Answer (score 0):

If its stored as a string in the database there is no method to do that in a SQL query. Your best chance would to write a custom MySQL [`FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) or fetch all rows and process them in your PHP script, but both are a relatively bad solution because envolve processing each row in the table. It can be both time and CPU consuming, specially if its a large table.

But there are methods of solving this problem, you only need to use the right structure in this table. What you need is a One-to-Many relationship. For instance, instead of having this structure:

```
| numbers
| "1, 2, 3, 4"
| "5, 6, 7, 8"
```

You would have this:

```
| group | number 
| 1     | 1
| 1     | 2
| 1     | 3
| 1     | 4
| 2     | 5
| 2     | 6
| 2     | 7
| 2     | 8
```

And then you can do:

```
$sql = "SELECT
            `group`,
             COUNT(*),
             GROUP_CONCAT(`number` SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM
            `table`
        WHERE
           `number` IN (2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
        GROUP BY
           `group`
        ORDER BY
           COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

echo "The group with most matches is the group {$row[0]}
      with {$row[1]} hits. The matching numbers were {$row[2]}.";
```